# Set the origin of newly created window Cocoa/Applescript

Tags: xcode, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm trying to create new window with given origin in Cocoa/AppleScript type  application.

I have Main NIB with main window and another one called `hud`. With button in main window I open new window (hud) in that way:
`set  winn to NSWindowController's alloc()'s initWithWindowNibName_("hud")
winn's showWindow_("jkb")`
The window is showing up.

I want to show it in different location on the screen but without any luck. I have tried every combination of those two:

`set myOrigin to {x:330,y:330}` or `set myOrigin to {330,330}`

with every line listed below:

`current application's winn's class "NSWindow"'s class "NSView"'s setFrameOrigin_(mySize)` --class "NSView" of class "NSWindow" of winn doesn’t understand the “setFrameOrigin_” message

`current application's winn's NSWindow's setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)` --NSWindow of winn doesn’t understand the “setFrameOrigin_” message

`current application's winn's class "NSView"'s setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)` --class "NSView" of winn doesn’t understand the “setFrameOrigin_” message

`current application's winn's jkb's class "NSView"'s setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)` --class "NSView" of jkb of winn doesn’t understand the “setFrameOrigin_” message

`current application's jkb's  class "NSView"'s setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)` --class "NSView" of jkb doesn’t understand the “setFrameOrigin_” message

`current application's jkb's  NSView's setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)` --NSView of jkb doesn’t understand the “setFrameOrigin_” message

`current application's jkb's class "NSView"'s setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)` --class "NSView" of jkb doesn’t understand the “setFrameOrigin_” message

`winn's jkb's class "NSView"'s setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)` --this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key jkb.

when I check through  `log ... frame` I see objects so why do they not respond to `setFrameOrgin_()` ?

Comment: `winn's setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)`?

Comment: This produce an error: `[AppDelegate openWindow:]: -[NSWindowController setFrameOrigin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180000963f0 (error -10000)`. `winn` is my `NSWindowController`, shouldn't I talk to the window itself?

Comment: `winn` is a `NSWindowController`. `setFrameOrigin` is a method of `NSWindow`. Try `winn's window's setFrameOrigin_(myOrigin)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. In `hud` nib I bind the window to a `property hudWindow: missing value` in a new, different script than main delegate. In this script I have created another method `awakeFromNib()`. When it is called I finally can point to the right object (`hudWindow`) and set its parameters. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go about this:

1. Through IB:

[image: IB]

2. Programatically:

Subclass `NSWindowController` and set the origin in `windowDidLoad:` with `window setFrame:`

Comment: Location of my opening window is dependend on windows of another apps so I can't use this method. Finally I come up with the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works in my app:

```
theWindow's setFrameTopLeftPoint:{60,460}
```

where `theWindow` is an **instance of** `NSWindow` (retrieved from the window controller)

Remember that {0,0} is the left,bottom of the main screen for this method.

Comment: How you access instance of a window controller? By the `windowController's theWindow` ? How you bind in that case theWindow to the window that isn't existing yet. Like in my case it will be opened when button is clicked.